# Jquery show hide multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a comment tree similar to Reddit's. People will need to be able to reply the comments by clicking a reply link, and then a form with a textarea should come. I tried using the `.show()` method, but there is more than one comment, and when you click reply it shows all the forms for every comment. How can i fix this? What should i look into?

Comment: Post the HTML you are using....it will help provide apt answer

Comment: Also post the javascript you have tried so far...

Comment: You have almost no description as to what you want, all you are telling us is that you are showing more than what you want to show. You really need to add coda, and edit for clarity.

Comment: no description? I found out. I used ajax to prevent this happening....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You'll need to set a class for each `textarea` (A different class for each one).
   Let's say:

   `<textarea class="commentAnswerBox1">Answer here...</textarea>`
2. Now you have to set up a class for each comment answer button
   Like this

   `<input type="button" class="btnAnswer1" value="Answer this comment" />`
3. Now you can call a function that recognizes which `btnAnswer` was clicked, and show only the correspondent `commentBox`.

You can use Class or IDs, or also create an attribute, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the issue stems from your DOM selector. It looks like you want to only show the last text area. If this is the case then you want something like

`$('textarea:last').show();`

Post more info so we can provide better answers.